# Redirect client while performing a function with Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request

Right now, I have an Express route that is posted to by a form, below is a truncated example. The initial form is inside an iframe, so after I receive a response from `http://example.com/endpoint`, I send a response back to the iframe with a link going to a "signing" page, targeting the parent frame.

Unfortunately, the response from `http://example.com/endpoint` can take pretty long, which causes the iframe to timeout and never receive a response. What I'd like to do is send some type of response back to the iframe immediately and redirect the page to some sort of "loading page" – this would be shown while the router waits for a response from `http://example.com/endpoint`.

I'm using Express to serve the page that contains the iframe to the user right now – all the views are controlled on the server side.

I'm wondering if there's any resources somebody could point me towards, or something to nudge me in the right direction.

```js
router.post('/api/orders', function(req, res) {

    var order = {
        'model': req.body.model,
        'options': optionsArray
    }

    request.post({
        url: 'http://example.com/endpoint,
        body: order,
        json: true
    }, function(err, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            if (!body.isCustom) {
                hellosign.embedded.getSignUrl(body.signatureId)
                    .then(function(response) {
                        var signatureUrl = response.embedded.sign_url;
                        var resSignatureUrl = encodeURIComponent(signatureUrl);
                        res.send('<a href="http://' + req.headers.host + '/order/sign/' + body.orderNumber + '?url=' + resSignatureUrl + '" target="_parent">Click to sign</a>');
                    })
                    .catch(function(err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    })
            } else {
                res.send('You selected custom options.');
            }
        }
        if (error || response.statusCode === 403) {
            res.json({
                message: 'something went wrong with your order',
                errorCode: response.statusCode,
                errorMessage: body.message
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Sounds like you need a job queue that the user can query or poll for the state of the job and redirect to the result when complete. Something like https://github.com/Automattic/kue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put the hellosign/whatever long running API call in its own module.  Test that separately to make sure its working.

Then your iframe or whatever (do you really need an iframe?) sends the request which is just a 'start order' request which gets an order id from the hellosign module.  And then use a setInterval or something to check a new endpoint which is an 'orderstatus' endpoint.

Your orderstatus endpoint accesses your new hellosign module to check the status of the order.

So it could be something like:

```
post('/start', function(req,res) {
  var id = hellosign.startorder(req.body.model);
  res.send(id);
});

get('/status', function(req,res) {
  res.send(hellosign.checkstatus(req.body.id));
}


// hellosign.js

var status = {};
exports.startorder = function(model) {
  var id = uuid.v4(); // some unique id;
  status[id] = 'started';
  request.post(api, /* ... */ ).then(function(signurl) { status[id] = signurl });
  return id;
}

exports.checkstatus = function(id) {
  return status[id];
}
```